# Can all image links available on internet can be used in json document?

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-glide

I am building an android app using android studio.
I am using api by uploading my json file on dropbox.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/45xopes03s1iyse/Movie.json?dl=0
I want to know the images that I have taken can be used in my project because they are not loading when I am using GLIDE to fetch images and app crashes.

Also the data doesn't get updated automatically I need to refresh again and again for the data to be displayed

CODE:

My Main Activity:

```
package com.example.amitc.pvrathome;

import android.app.usage.UsageEvents;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class movies_tab extends AppCompatActivity {

    //private static final String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/45xopes03s1iyse/Movie.json?dl=1";
    private static final String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/45xopes03s1iyse/Movie.json?dl=1";
    private ArrayList<String> m_name = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_release_year = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_genre = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_desc = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_director = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_rating = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_actor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_imgsrc = new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayList<String> m_name1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_release_year1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_genre1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_director1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_rating1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_actor1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_desc1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_imgsrc1 = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies_tab);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // add back arrow to toolbar
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("movies");


                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = o.getString("name");
                                String year = o.getString("year");
                                String genre = o.getString("genre");
                                String rating = o.getString("rating");
                                String director = o.getString("directors_name");
                                String actor = o.getString("cast");
                                String img_src = o.getString("poster_src");
                                String desc = o.getString("description");

                                m_name.add(name);
                                m_release_year.add(year);
                                m_genre.add(genre);
                                m_rating.add(rating);
                                m_director.add(director);
                                m_actor.add(actor);
                                m_imgsrc.add(img_src);
                                m_desc.add(desc);

                                m_name1.add(name);
                                m_release_year1.add(year);
                                m_genre1.add(genre);
                                m_rating1.add(rating);
                                m_director1.add(director);
                                m_actor1.add(actor);
                                m_imgsrc1.add(img_src);
                                m_desc1.add(desc);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        initRecyclerView1();
        initRecyclerView1();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void initRecyclerView() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview.");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.newest);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(m_name, m_release_year, m_genre, m_desc, m_director, m_rating, m_actor, m_imgsrc, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    public void initRecyclerView1() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview.");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.hottest);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(m_name1, m_release_year1, m_genre1, m_desc1, m_director1, m_rating1, m_actor1, m_imgsrc1, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    public void gotoHome(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    public void gotoMovies(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.movie_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, movies_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoSeries(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.series_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, series_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoSpecials(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.specials_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, specials_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoActors(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.actors_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, actors_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoFavourites(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favorites_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, favorite_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoDownloads(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.downloads_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, downloaded_tab.class));
    }
}
```

ADAPTER:

```
package com.example.amitc.pvrathome;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<String> m_name = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_year = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_genre = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_images = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_desc = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_director = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_rating = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_stars = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> m_name, ArrayList<String> m_year, ArrayList<String> m_genre, ArrayList<String> m_desc, ArrayList<String> m_director, ArrayList<String> m_rating, ArrayList<String> m_stars, ArrayList<String> images,  Context mContext) {
        this.m_name = m_name;
        this.m_year = m_year;
        this.m_genre = m_genre;
        this.m_desc = m_desc;
        this.m_director = m_director;
        this.m_rating = m_rating;
        this.m_stars = m_stars;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.m_images = images;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

//        Glide.with(mContext)
//                .asBitmap()
//                .load(m_images.get(i))
//                .into(viewHolder.img);



        viewHolder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, msms.class);
                intent.putExtra("names", m_name.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("genres", m_genre.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("years", m_year.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("stars", m_stars.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("decs", m_desc.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("direcs", m_director.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("ratings", m_rating.get(i));
                intent.putExtra("img1", m_images.get(i));

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
        });

        viewHolder.names.setText(m_name.get(i));
        viewHolder.years.setText(m_year.get(i));
        viewHolder.genres.setText(m_genre.get(i));

//        Glide.with(mContext)
//                .asBitmap()
//                .load(m_images.get(i))
//                .into(viewHolder.img1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return m_name.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        LinearLayout parentLayout;
        TextView names;
        TextView years;
        TextView genres;
        TextView actors;
        ImageView img;
        ImageView img1;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dabba);
            names = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_name);
            years = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_year);
            genres = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_genre);
            //img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dabba);
            img1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.msms_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Another Adapter inside Adapter:

```
package com.example.amitc.pvrathome;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.SimpleTarget;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.transition.Transition;

public class msms extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.msms);

        getIncomingIntent();
    }

    private void getIncomingIntent()
    {
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("names");
        String name1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("names");
        String year = getIntent().getStringExtra("years");
        String genre = getIntent().getStringExtra("genres");
        String rating = getIntent().getStringExtra("ratings");
        String desc = getIntent().getStringExtra("decss");
        String director = getIntent().getStringExtra("direcs");
        String actor = getIntent().getStringExtra("stars");
        String img_src = getIntent().getStringExtra("img_src");


        TextView m_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msms_name);
        m_name.setText(name);

        TextView m_name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msms_name1);
        m_name1.setText(name);
//        TextView m_year = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msms_year);
//        m_year.setText(year);

        TextView m_genre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msms_genre);
        m_genre.setText(genre);

        TextView m_rating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msms_rating);
        m_rating.setText(rating);

        TextView m_desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msms_desc);
        m_desc.setText(desc);

        TextView m_direc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msms_direc);
        m_direc.setText(director);

        TextView m_actor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msms_actor);
        m_actor.setText(actor);

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.msms_image);
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(img_src)
                .into(imageView);
```

}

Updated main activity:

```
package com.example.amitc.pvrathome;

import android.app.usage.UsageEvents;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class movies_tab extends AppCompatActivity {

    //private static final String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/45xopes03s1iyse/Movie.json?dl=1";
    private static final String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/45xopes03s1iyse/Movie.json?dl=1";
    private ArrayList<String> m_name = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_release_year = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_genre = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_desc = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_director = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_rating = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_actor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_imgsrc = new ArrayList<>();
    StringRequest stringRequest;
    private ArrayList<String> m_name1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_release_year1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_genre1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_director1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_rating1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_actor1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_desc1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> m_imgsrc1 = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies_tab);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // add back arrow to toolbar
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }


        new fetchdata().execute();
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


        initRecyclerView();

        initRecyclerView1();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void initRecyclerView() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview.");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.newest);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(m_name, m_release_year, m_genre, m_desc, m_director, m_rating, m_actor, m_imgsrc, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    public void initRecyclerView1() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview.");
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.hottest);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(m_name1, m_release_year1, m_genre1, m_desc1, m_director1, m_rating1, m_actor1, m_imgsrc1, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }

    public void gotoHome(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    public void gotoMovies(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.movie_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, movies_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoSeries(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.series_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, series_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoSpecials(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.specials_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, specials_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoActors(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.actors_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, actors_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoFavourites(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favorites_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, favorite_tab.class));
    }

    public void gotoDownloads(View v) {
        //ImageView btn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.downloads_button);
        startActivity(new Intent(movies_tab.this, downloaded_tab.class));
    }


    public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("movies");


                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = o.getString("name");
                                String year = o.getString("year");
                                String genre = o.getString("genre");
                                String rating = o.getString("rating");
                                String director = o.getString("directors_name");
                                String actor = o.getString("cast");
                                String img_src = o.getString("poster_src");
                                String desc = o.getString("description");

                                m_name.add(name);
                                m_release_year.add(year);
                                m_genre.add(genre);
                                m_rating.add(rating);
                                m_director.add(director);
                                m_actor.add(actor);
                                m_imgsrc.add(img_src);
                                m_desc.add(desc);

                                m_name1.add(name);
                                m_release_year1.add(year);
                                m_genre1.add(genre);
                                m_rating1.add(rating);
                                m_director1.add(director);
                                m_actor1.add(actor);
                                m_imgsrc1.add(img_src);
                                m_desc1.add(desc);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can also upload the source code if anyone can help me!

Comment: Showing the code is always a good idea, and is somehow expected and required by the community, with very few exceptions. If the code is very lengthy, upload it to something like pastebin. Under no circumstances, show your code as image (screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

U can use glide to load any image from the internet and display in ImageView, but some times depending on the server configuration you can't do that but 99% of the time it should work.

For the data to refresh automatically you have multiple options to fix, here are two:

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

The second one is preferred.

For the app crash, please specify the error meassage and post the code that is causing the crash

Comment: Sir I have uploaded the code please check if you can!
And please tell where to exactly add Asynctask?

Comment: I have added Async Task Successfully but it is not helping
Now also I need to refresh multiple times to display the data.

Comment: in ur adapter u need to set the image with glide like this:Glide.with(mContext).load(m_images.get(i)).into(viewHolder.img1);

Comment: another thing to do is instead of creating a million arraylists, create a model class that represent ur data then create a single arraylist and pass the class as the array type, here is a link on how to do such thing: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USbTcGx1mD0&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjHrGKo9GqOtLs1e2bglHHA